# VBA create multiple SaveCopyAs workbooks and store formulas in-between the loops for next loop

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to cut multiple versions of one workbook (one for each country manager). I want to create them as SaveCopyAs version as there will be several worksheets that are the same for each country manager. I have created a loop and after each loop I restore the original worksheet before the next loop starts. Unfortunately the original worksheet is only restored with values and the formulas are gone. How do I keep the formulas? any help is appreciated.

```
Sub Split_Data_in_workbooks()

Application.ScreenUpdating = False

Dim data_sh As Worksheet
Set data_sh = Workbooks.Open("H:\VBA\TestChart_functions.xlsx").Sheets("Data")

Dim setting_Sh As Worksheet
Set setting_Sh = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Settings")


Dim original_wb As Workbook
Set original_wb = ActiveWorkbook

''''' Get unique country managers

setting_Sh.Range("A:A").Clear
data_sh.AutoFilterMode = False
data_sh.Range("D:D").Copy setting_Sh.Range("A1")

setting_Sh.Range("A:A").RemoveDuplicates 1, xlYes

Dim i As Integer

For i = 2 To Application.CountA(setting_Sh.Range("A:A"))

data_sh.UsedRange.AutoFilter 4, Criteria1:="<>" & setting_Sh.Range("A" & i)
data_sh.UsedRange.AutoFilter 3, Criteria1:="<>keep"


Dim lastValues As Variant

    With Range("A2:B16") '<--| reference your relevant range
        lastValues = .Value '<--| first, store its content in the worksheet scoped array variable
        .ClearContents '<--| then, clear its content
    End With

data_sh.AutoFilterMode = False

original_wb.SaveCopyAs setting_Sh.Range("H6").Value & "/" & setting_Sh.Range("A" & i).Value & ".xlsx"

Range("A2:B16").Value = lastValues '<--| write'em back!

Next i

setting_Sh.Range("A:A").Clear

MsgBox "Done"

End Sub
```

Comment: Do you have AutoSave enabled?

Answer (score 0):

I am not able to add a comment so adding my option as answer. From your question what I understand is that you need to maintain the formula in the particular column, if so please use `.Formula` for that column as below example:
`Working_Sheet.Range("F" & i).Formula = "=COUNTIF($E$" & 2 & ":E" & i & ",E" & i & ")"`
this will maintain the formula in the column.

Answer (score 0):

When inputting anything into a cell, I generally use `.formula =`
(even if it is a value I put in).

When reading anything from a cell I use `.formula` to read its formula, or `.value2` to read most other things.

So I would be using `.formula` for both these actions:

`<--| first, store its content in the worksheet scoped array variable`

and

`'<--| write'em back!`

Comment: that was helpful. Unfortunately I have run into another issue now. beneath my data table I have got a summary table with sum formulas to add up and group the data from the data table. somehow that gets lost when I am running the second loop. I think I need a different solution to restore the deleted data in between the loops. How can I restore the original worksheet including all formulas and formatting in between the loops? So I am running through loop 1 and then before running through loop 2, so the worksheet looks exactly the same before I started the first loop. any help is appreciated

Comment: Glad it was helpful - feel free to mark as answer to help future readers. With your new issue you could try restoring or re-opening the original workbook after loop 1 to restore it to its previously saved state. If you get stuck just start a new question about it.